# $L^2$ and $L_z$ of a Quantum System

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential, schroedinger-equation

Let's assume I have a 3D Box problem (which is considered as a  particle  a  box).I'm considering that  I have  a fermion which is in the 3rd  excited state in the box. What can infer about the $L_z$  and $L^2$ from the  state?

Comment: if it’s a square box not much since the potential does not have spherical symmetry.

Comment: so  a particle  in a  3D particle box  doesn't  have any  information  about angular  momentum? 

So you are saying  if it is a spherical  box with infinite  potential  around the barrier, there  will be  angular momentum  of the Eigen states?

Comment: basically yes.  angular momentum is associated with spherical symmetry, not Cartesian.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero but you can still use those operators to get stuff like expectation values, etc. of those operators in those states right? Just because the system does not have spherical symmetry doesn't mean the operators are not valid.

Comment: @AaronStevens of course the operators are “valid” and you can act on any state.  However, the eigenstates of $H$ are not eigenstates of $L_z$ or $L^2$, and vice versa, so introducing those operators here does not provide very much mileage.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Just because they do not have a common eigenbasis doesn't mean there isn't information to be learned. You can still express this eigenfunction of $H$ in the eigenbasis of these operators to learn about measuring the angular momentum. I feel like this is what the OP is asking about. Just because you don't think it's a question that needs to be answered doesn't mean the OP thinks so.

Comment: @AaronStevens see my detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the box is Cartesian, then the eigenstates of $H$ are simple products of the form 
$$
\phi_{n_x,n_y,n_z}(x,y,z)=\psi_{n_x}(x)\psi_{n_y}(y)\psi_{n_z}(z) \tag{1}
$$
where $\psi_{n_x}(x)$ is the $n_x$’th eigenstate of the square well etc.

Unfortunately, the Hamiltonian for this system is not rotationally invariant, i.e. it does not commute with any component $L_x,L_y,L_z$ or with $L^2$.  Thus, the solutions (1) do not have good angular momentum quantum numbers, i.e. 
$$
L^2 \phi_{n_x,n_y,n_z}(x,y,z) \ne \hbar^2\ell (\ell+1) \phi_{n_x,n_y,n_z}(x,y,z)\, .
$$

Of course, it is possible to construct angular momentum operators $\hat L_z$ etc but as there is no obvious physics that comes out of using these operators what’s the point?

Of course if you want you can write the functions of (1) in terms of solutions of the spherical 3D well, for which the radial part is spherical Bessel function and the angular part is a spherical harmonic.  However, one is then faced with a different problem: to obtain a complete set of basis states for the spherical problem one needs to impose a boundary condition on $r$, i.e. the spherical Bessel functions (which depend on $r$) must be made to vanish at $r=r_0$, where $r_0$ is the edge of the well.  This value of $r_0$ cannot be constructed for a square well since the well is square.

In other words, there is no obvious way to map the boundary conditions on the edges of the square to a boundary condition on the radius of a spherical well, and vice versa, so there’s no obvious way of choosing a complete set of spherical Bessel functions for the expansion.